# FlowLayout not going to new line

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, flowlayout

I'm trying to add a variable number of JPanels (each one containst 2 Label) inside another JPanel using the FlowLayout.
When there's too many panels added instead of going to the new row they disappear out of the border

I've tried many types of Layouts, setting sizes, maximussizes but nothing changes.

```
public class AlbumView extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    private Album A;

    public AlbumView()
    {
        initComponents();
        A = new Album();

        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int w = this.getSize().width;
        int h = this.getSize().height;
        int x = (dim.width-w)/2;
        int y = (dim.height-h)/2;
        this.setLocation(x, y);

        pnlCategorie.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING, 10, 10));

        /*
        Insert of many elements in the Album
        */

        aggiornaAlbum();
    }

    public void aggiornaAlbum()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < A.getDim(); i++)
        {
            Categoria c = A.getCategoria(i);

            JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
            pnl.setName(c.getNome());
            JLabel lb1, lb2;
            ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(c.getPhoto(0).getImg(95, 95));  //da cambiare lo 0 con un numero casuale tra le foto disponibili
            lb1 = new JLabel(img, JLabel.CENTER);
            lb2 = new JLabel(c.getNome(), JLabel.CENTER);


            pnl.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pnl, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

            pnl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
            pnl.add(lb1);
            pnl.add(lb2);
            //pnl.revalidate();
            //pnl.repaint();

            pnlCategorie.add(pnl);
        }

        //ADDED AFTER COMMENT, NOTHING CHANGED (but probably it's because i didn't get exaclty what to do
        pnlCategorie.revalidate();
        pnlCategorie.repaint();
    }
```

pnlCategorie is created using NetBeans swing.

I expect that after the number of jpanels that fits the bigger jPanel the next one goes to a new line

Example of what is appearing (I'm using some exaple image, don't judge) :
[image: Example]

Comment: It works fine for me. Consider creating a [mcve] in order to get more accurate help.

Comment: 1) The revalidate() and repaint() should be done on the "bigPanel" outside of the loop. That is you only want to invoke the layout manager once, after all components have been added. 2) The components do flow to the next line. The problem is where you add the "bigPanel" to. The preferred size of the "bigPanel" doesn't change, so unless you add the "bigPanel" to the CENTER of the BorderLayout of the frame, you won't see the child components. Instead you can use the [Wrap Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/)

Comment: I've cutted a good portion of the code trying to leave the interested part. I'll try do add some more, maybe some screenshots too

Comment: *I've cutted a good portion of the code* - that is still not an [mre]. We can't compile and execute that code. The images are irrelevant to your question. All you need is a bunch of JLabels with text to text the wrapping. In any case you've already been given an answer.

Comment: Can you please be more specific regarding the answer? I'm sorry but english is not my main language so I'm not getting what you're trying to suggest...

Comment: Did you follow the link provided in my original comment? do you have question about what you read in the link?

Comment: EDIT: With the Wrap Layout it's working, thank you very much.
I still would like to know in detail what was the problem with the FlowLayout, just for a personal knoledge :D

Comment: I didn't get the "The components do flow to the next line. The problem is where you add the "bigPanel" to. The preferred size of the "bigPanel" doesn't change, so unless you add the "bigPanel" to the CENTER of the BorderLayout of the frame, you won't see the child components." part.
Can you explain it in detail if possible? Thanks

Comment: Again, did you read the link provided. It is a more detailed explanation of why the WrapLayout can be used to replace the FlowLayout. I can't explain exactly why your code doesn't work because you still haven't posted an [mre], so I can only give the general reason why I think it doesn't work. The problem is how you nest panels with different layout managers.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help :D